# Managing pip in an RPM environment

Tags: python, pip, rpm, yum, package-managers

For our prod apps, we manage all packages in RPM. In a perfect yum-only world, this is fine.

However, each language or framework recently are deploying their own package managers. For python for example, I am almost always using pip and then having to build the packages for rpm again when going to production. Same goes for npm or gems.

Is this an issue that a lot of people here are running into? What is best way to avoid all this? Are people dealing with this by just sucking it up and packaging everything manually, or is there some automated way to integrate them?

I would love to hear thoughts on this.

Answer (score 8):

I have used [pyp2rpm](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyp2rpm) to build rpm package for *rstr* module and I dislike random installations of some files via *pip* as well:

```
pyp2rpm -n rstr > ~/rpmbuild/SPECS/rstr.spec
rpmbuild -ba ~/rpmbuild/SPECS/rstr.spec
```

but I do not know if this is good enough for your production use.

Comment: Great. Had to deal with the fact that RPM on EL6 doesn't define __python2 macro, but other than that it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 5):

You can install fpm: https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm

> Effing package management! Build packages for multiple platforms (deb, rpm, etc) with great ease and sanity. http://fpm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Next you can run:

```
$ fpm -s python -t rpm pyramid
no value for epoch is set, defaulting to nil {:level=>:warn}
no value for epoch is set, defaulting to nil {:level=>:warn}
Created package {:path=>"python-pyramid-1.9a2-1.noarch.rpm"}
```

-s source type
-t type of package to create
and as last parameter the name of the package

https://fpm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/python.html

Comment: No SRPM.  The lack of transparency means it's an instant failure.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer installing to a different sitelib than the default system one. Hence I do:

```
$ pip install --user django
```

Far from ideal, doesn't play with dnf/rpm/yum but at the same time doesn't mess with your system modules. And you can wipe them whenever you want.

Comment: .. doesn't play with RPM/DNF/YUM, but also doesn't play with SNMP reporting or anything that leverages the same routines.  So be CAREFUL if you install software this way, as it's just like spraying a tarball onto your box in terms of any proper centralized management.  And one day that will make you sad.